# How can I gather different columns into one in R?

Tags: r, data-wrangling

I have some geographical data that kinda looks like this:

| name | x1 | x2 | x3 | x4 | y1 | y2 | y3 | y4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mark | 5 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 3 | 2 | 5 |
| Amy | 0 | 5 | 1 | 5 | 0 | 3 | 2 | 5 |

And I would like to transform it into something like this to graph it easier on ggplot:

| name | x | y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mark | 5 | 0 |
| Mark | 2 | 3 |
| Mark | 1 | 2 |
| Mark | 2 | 5 |
| Amy | 0 | 0 |
| Amy | 5 | 3 |
| Amy | 1 | 2 |
| Amy | 5 | 5 |

I have tried the function `gather()` without any success.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It should be easier with `pivot_longer` which is a successor of `gather`.

```
tidyr::pivot_longer(df, 
                    cols = -name, 
                    names_to = '.value', 
                    names_pattern = '([a-z])\\d+')

#  name      x     y
#  <chr> <int> <int>
#1 Mark      5     0
#2 Mark      2     3
#3 Mark      1     2
#4 Mark      2     5
#5 Amy       0     0
#6 Amy       5     3
#7 Amy       1     2
#8 Amy       5     5
```